# Django Background Tasks not working with Apache + mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, background-task

I use django-background-tasks to run some heavy tasks in the background in my Django application. On my local machine everything works fine. However, if I deploy my application in production with Apache and mod_wsgi, the scheduled tasks are not executed. Instead, if I run the command

```
python manage.py process_tasks
```

in some terminal, the message

```
'Failed to retrieve tasks. Database unreachable.'
```

is printed every 5 sec or so.

What am I doing wrong? Where/how am I supposed to run "python manage.py process_tasks"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use cron service

```
 * * * * * /path/to/virtualenv/bin/python /path/to/project/manage.py process_tasks
```

you can learn more https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux

Comment: This just repeatedly executes the process_tasks command, while still getting the 'Failed to retrieve tasks. Database unreachable.' error.